# Nancy does not render the view nor extending the layout view

Tags: c#, mono, nancy

I started learning about C# in Mono (Ubuntu) and [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Introduction) which is a web framework for C#. I am using their "super simple view engine" rendering and I cannot make the code to render the `.sshtml` file, it just shows as plan text file. Ultimately, I want to use a layout file (`layout.sshtml`) and each view would replace part of layout file.

I have a hunch that maybe folder structure is not valid and for example `login.sshtml` does not find the `layout.sshtml`. But I modified the `.csproj` file to copy Views folders:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <!-- needed to deply views folder -->
    <Exec Command="cp -a  Views $(OutDir)" />
    <!-- needed to deply database if not newer -->
    <Exec Command="cp -a -u  Database/db.sqlite $(OutDir)" />
  </Target>
```

I am just confused on why it does not render the view. Any help would be appreciated.

[This is the link to my repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/nancy-simple-app/tree/bb69b23da247a1c29f949cf76b196775161a45b2)

This is folder structure of my project:

```
├── bin
│   └── Debug
│       ├── csharp-practice.exe
│       ├── csharp-practice.exe.mdb
│       ├── db.sqlite
│       ├── Nancy.dll
│       ├── Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll
│       ├── nancy-simple-app.exe
│       ├── nancy-simple-app.exe.mdb
│       └── Views
│           ├── index.sshtml
│           ├── layout.sshtml
│           ├── login.sshtml
│           └── register.sshtml
├── Database
│   ├── DataBaseManager.cs
│   └── db.sqlite
├── LICENSE
├── nancy-simple-app.csproj
├── nancy-simple-app.sln
├── nancy-simple-app.userprefs
├── obj
│   └── x86
│       └── Debug
│           ├── csharp-practice.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt
│           ├── csharp-practice.exe
│           ├── csharp-practice.exe.mdb
│           ├── nancy-simple-app.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt
│           ├── nancy-simple-app.exe
│           └── nancy-simple-app.exe.mdb
├── packages
│   ├── Nancy.1.4.3
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   └── net40
│   │   │       ├── Nancy.dll
│   │   │       └── Nancy.xml
│   │   └── Nancy.1.4.3.nupkg
│   ├── Nancy.Hosting.Self.1.4.1
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   └── net40
│   │   │       ├── Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll
│   │   │       └── Nancy.Hosting.Self.xml
│   │   └── Nancy.Hosting.Self.1.4.1.nupkg
│   └── repositories.config
├── packages.config
├── Program.cs
├── Properties
│   └── AssemblyInfo.cs
├── ViewModels
│   └── UserModel.cs
└── Views
    ├── index.sshtml
    ├── layout.sshtml
    ├── login.sshtml
    └── register.sshtml
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution, the issue was using double quotes instead of single quotes in [Views folder](https://github.com/amir734jj/nancy-simple-app/tree/bb69b23da247a1c29f949cf76b196775161a45b2/Views)

For example, change this:

```
@Master["layout"]


@Section["content"]
   This is content on the register page
@EndSection
```

to this:

```
@Master['layout']


@Section['content']
   This is content on the register page
@EndSection
```

I don't know why, but it solved the layout issue.

[By the day, this is the link to working website, it just a simple login, logout, register website.](https://github.com/amir734jj/nancy-simple-app)

Comment: Super simple view engine really is pretty simple and does not try to be overly flexible. The single quotes that you ended up with are just what the documentation says :) https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Super-Simple-View-Engine#master-pages-and-sections If you want a more advancedserver side view engine, you could try Razor (https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine). Or you could, of course, move to a client side framework.